# Train part of the network

Tags: pytorch

I am new to Deep Learning and Pytorch. I have the following problem:

My overall architecture consists of a network that I define (NN1), and another pretrained network (NN2), so that the output of NN1 is the input of NN2. I want to define the loss of NN1 using the difference (RMSE) between the output of NN2 and a know ground-truth. 
I need to back-propagate through NN2 and NN1 (to train NN1), without changing NN2.

I can use `requires_grad=False` on NN2, but will it disable the back-propagation through NN2? How do I specify this requirement in Pytorch?

Thanks.

Comment: Normally `requires_grad=False` should do but I'm not sure about it. Maybe you should try train on a single batch of data to see if it converge(make it overfit on purpose). If it does then this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use two different modules. The first will be your module/model/NN (the NN1) and the second the pretrained one.

Then, you will use `model_nn1.train()` and `model_nn2.eval()`. Then, you can do:

```py
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model_nn1.parameters())  # You can use your own preferred optimizer

model_nn1.train()
model_nn2.eval()

for epoch in range(epochs):
  for x, y in dataloader:  # the dataloader is your dataloader according to the torch.utils.data.DataLoader
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    h_nn1 = model_nn1(x) # x is the input
    y_hat = model_nn2(h_nn1) # y_hat is the output
    loss = torch.sqrt(torch.mean((yhat-y)**2))
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

You can check the requirement about gradient doing:

```py
>>> import torch
>>> x = torch.nn.Linear(2, 3)
>>> x2 = torch.nn.Linear(3, 2)
>>> z = torch.rand(2, 2)
>>> y = torch.rand(2, 2)
>>> x.train()
Linear(in_features=2, out_features=3, bias=True)
>>> x2.eval()
Linear(in_features=3, out_features=2, bias=True)
>>> h = x(z)
>>> h.requires_grad
True
>>> y_hat = x2(h)
>>> y_hat.requires_grad
True
```